# Is the "www" in the database for the site confguration?

Tags: database, subsites

I have recently helped launch a site and there are some cross domain issues between "www.website.com" and "website.com"

I was chatting with Cloudways tech support and he mentioned that if I remove the "www" from the database for my site settings I wouldn't be having the issue.

What I ended up doing was modifying the `.htaccess` to redirect to "www.website.com" for now, but I still have the question: Is the "www" for the domain name in site information stored in the database? If so, would you really want to edit that?

[image: Site info screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not there in database.

It depends on [global $base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7) variable.

[How drupal define](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_settings_initialize/7) this variable is based on super global $_SERVER['HOST'] variable, which is basically depends on how the request was sent with/without www.

But you can override global $base_url in your settings.php
$base_url = 'http://yoursite.com'